# Error when reading data from SQL Server Express

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-express, sqldatareader

I have a very simple select statement but I cannot for life of me see what is wrong. I OBV masked my real database and server name for the post.

```
public List<Customer> CustomersGetAll()
{
        var customers = new List<Customer>();
        Customer customer;

        using (var command = new SqlCommand())
        {
            command.Connection = _connection;
            command.CommandText =
                " SELECT Id, Reference, Name, SupplierGln, GLN, UseCustomerProductCodes, IncludeBranchInvoices, RequireBuyerOrderNoAndDate, RequireQuantityOfTradedUnits, " + 
                "RequireQuantityOfTradedUnits, DefaultBranchCode FROM Customer ORDER BY Reference ";

            using (SqlDataReader reader =  command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    customer = new Customer();
                    customer.ID = (int)reader["Id"];
                    customer.Reference = (string)reader["reference"];
                    customer.Name = (string)reader["Name"];
                    customer.SupplierGLN = (string) reader["SupplierGLN"];
                    customer.GLN = (string)reader["GLN"];
                    customer.IncludeBranchInvoices = (bool)reader["IncludeBranchInvoices"];
                    customer.UseBuyerProductCodes = (bool)reader["UseCustomerProductCodes"];
                    customer.RequireBuyerOrderNoAndDate = (bool)reader["RequireBuyerOrderNoAndDate"];
                    customer.RequireReturnToSupplierNoForCredit = (bool)reader["RequireQuantityOfTradedUnits"];
                    customer.RequireQuantityOfTradedUnits = (bool)reader["RequireQuantityOfTradedUnits"];
                    customer.DefaultBranchCode = reader["DefaultBranchCode"] as string;

                    foreach (var productCode in CustomerProductCodesGetByCustomerID(customer.ID))
                    {
                        customer.ProductCodes.Add(productCode.Key, productCode.Value);
                    }

                    foreach (var branchCode in GetCustomerBranchCodes(customer.ID))
                    {
                        customer.BranchCodes.Add(branchCode.Key, branchCode.Value);
                    }

                    customers.Add(customer);
                }
            }
        }

        return customers.ToList();
 }
```

I am using SQL Server 2017 Express and have the following as my connection string:

```
public DatabaseEngine(string databasePath)
{
        try
        {
            _connectionString = string.Format("Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;", @"MACHINENAME\SQLEXPRESS2017", "DBNAME");

            _connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);

            _connection.Open();
        }
        catch
        {
            if (_connection != null)
            {
                _connection.Close();
                _connection = null;
            }

            throw;
        }
 }
```

This is the routine that fires the error shown below:

```
 /// </summary>
 private void LoadCustomers()
 {
    cboCustomers.Items.Clear();
   _customers = _database.CustomersGetAll();

   if (_customers != null)
   {
       foreach (Customer customer in _customers)
       {
          cboCustomers.Items.Add(customer);
        }
   }
 }
```

Which all works and it does get connected to the database fine but I get the following error I already have tried the following

```
MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
```

Which is the recommended fix for the below error but its not happening for me ?.

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.

[image]

**Edit 1**
So I cahnged my above query and I am still getting the same error above I rebooted the  sql box in case something was being held on to as there is not.

```
  public List<Customer> CustomersGetAll()
    {
        var customers = new List<Customer>();
        Customer customer;

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {


                string sql =
                    " SELECT Id, Reference, Name, SupplierGln, GLN, UseCustomerProductCodes, IncludeBranchInvoices, RequireBuyerOrderNoAndDate, RequireQuantityOfTradedUnits, " +
                    "RequireQuantityOfTradedUnits, DefaultBranchCode FROM Customer ORDER BY Reference ";

            using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql,connection))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        customer = new Customer();
                        customer.ID = (int)reader["Id"];
                        customer.Reference = (string)reader["reference"];
                        customer.Name = (string)reader["Name"];
                        customer.SupplierGLN = (string)reader["SupplierGLN"];
                        customer.GLN = (string)reader["GLN"];
                        customer.IncludeBranchInvoices = (bool)reader["IncludeBranchInvoices"];
                        customer.UseBuyerProductCodes = (bool)reader["UseCustomerProductCodes"];
                        customer.RequireBuyerOrderNoAndDate = (bool)reader["RequireBuyerOrderNoAndDate"];
                        customer.RequireReturnToSupplierNoForCredit = (bool)reader["RequireQuantityOfTradedUnits"];
                        customer.RequireQuantityOfTradedUnits = (bool)reader["RequireQuantityOfTradedUnits"];
                        customer.DefaultBranchCode = reader["DefaultBranchCode"] as string;

                        foreach (var productCode in CustomerProductCodesGetByCustomerID(customer.ID))
                        {
                            customer.ProductCodes.Add(productCode.Key, productCode.Value);
                        }

                        foreach (var branchCode in GetCustomerBranchCodes(customer.ID))
                        {
                            customer.BranchCodes.Add(branchCode.Key, branchCode.Value);
                        }

                        customers.Add(customer);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return customers.ToList();
    }
```

Comment: Not to derail you, but have you considered Dapper?

Comment: @ParrishHusband Sorry the customer works on MS techs this is not a site for product promotion.

Comment: Dapper is just an ORM, but it's written on the .NET stack.  https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/blob/master/Readme.md

Comment: I would change your code to use a new connection when invoking commands.  You don't need an open database connection when the app is idle

Comment: Hi all it appears to be this object that is casuing issue now
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
                    {

Answer (score 2):

```
command.Connection = _connection;
```

don't do this. connection should be disposed after you are done with current section.

.NET will maintain an internal connection pool for you so you shouldn't have to worry about the cost of opening a new connection each time.

In fact if you try to use the same connection twice without closing the previous one you will be getting the error you are seeing.

Comment: please see edit 1 above did so and removed all command.connections

Comment: @david whats CustomerProductCodesGetByCustomerID and GetCustomerBranchCodes

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may work for you:

```
public List<Customer> CustomersGetAll()
{
    var customers = new List<Customer>();
    Customer customer;
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(connection))
    {
        // do work...
```

Also you can avoid hard-coding your data providers by utilizing the `System.Data.Common` namespace and `DbProviderFactory`.